# How statistics play a major role in legacy CE vs new CE

Tags: sql-server, query-performance, sql-server-2014, statistics, cardinality-estimates

We have quite some issues going on for one of our SQL server 2014 SP3 after compatibility change to 120 from 100.

Yes i am aware of few hints to make use of legacy CE and have implemented as success. However i am trying to understand exaclty what changes with stats for table over 1 Billion rows and approx some 500 Gb size

For the database in question we have some 8-10 VLtables starting with 500 M rows gows all the way to 4 billion rows. Update stats had been a problem with higher sample rate so we just do default sample rate.
like UPDATE STATS "IX_NAME"

I have couple of questions - does new CE prefers to have better stats like updating stats on higher sample rate?

If yes how better can i plan to update stats for very large tables so that they do not run for hours and just finish in time if we go with daily stats?

FYI- Auto update stats is on but for VLTB they hardly come into effect because of old algorithim